# What is the probability to get $4$ digit number that can be arranged as its opposite using the $9$ theorem from $1$ to $10,000$?

Tags: probability, arithmetic

Such 3 numbers that meet the following conditions:

$$  a \ne b \ne n $$

$$ 0 \lt a,b \lt 10 $$
$$ 0 \le n \lt 10 $$

The number that we want to know can be given from the following equation:

$$ 1000a + 110n + b $$

When $$ a < b $$
then we do:

$$ 1000a + 110n + b + 999(b-a) $$

EXAMPLE

$$  a = 3         $$
$$ b =  9 $$
$$ n = 0 $$

So

$$1000(3) + 110(0) + 9 = 3009 $$

We can form its inverse by:

$$ 3009 + (9-3)999 = 3009 + 5994 = 9003 $$

So, given that we can assume the following things:

We are searching number so $a < b$, so:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1,2 & 2,3\\
        1,3 & 2,4\\
        1,4 & 2,5\\
        1,5 & 2,6 & ...\\
        1,6 & 2,7\\
        1,7 & 2,8\\
        1,8 & 2,9\\
        1,9 \\
       \end{matrix}
$$

We see this and we notice that the total combinations of the numbers is a sum of consecutive numbers, starting with 8 so:
$$ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 9(4) = 36 $$

And we have only ten possible solutions in the middle part of the number:

$$ \begin{matrix}
        00 \\
        11 \\
        22 \\
       ...
\end {matrix}
$$
So all the numbers that can be done it's all the combinations gotten above $(36)$
 and multiply by all the combinations of the middle part of the number $(10)$

...

$$ 36(10) = 360  $$

We know that we have 10,000 numbers, so we get the following thing:

$$ \frac{360}{10,000} = \frac {9}{250} $$

My question is...am I right? If I am, did you see something that was wrong? Otherwise, where did I make the mistake and how would be the procedure?

Good night :)

EDIT: I'm starting to learn how to use the code so if anyone sees this and notice a mistake or you can suggest something to make this posts better, please let me know (the procedure it's the same).

Comment: Yoi have probably written $c$ instead of $b$ a couple of times. That said, are you asking how many four digits number have the third digit equal to the second?

Comment: Excluding all the palindrome numbers. (Thank you for the correction)

Comment: Then if you are asking the probability of getting a non-palindrome four digits number with the second digit equal to the third by picking between every number from 1 to 10.000 you are wrong by a factor 2, given that, for example, 3.009 and 9.003 are both good picks

Comment: I forgot to add something, while it's true that they are both picks I cannot apply the trick, to use the method described above the digits of the units must be greater than the digits of the  thousands.

Comment: You can apply the trick, is just that $b-a$ happens to be negative. That said if you want $a<b$ your reasoning is right

Comment: ...That's right, I should have been more precise. Thank you.